# Background color for inline math with linebreaks?

Tags: formatting, color, backgrounds, inline

What's the simplest way to achieve coloured background for the inline equation in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Completely unimportant text 
$ABC_{1234} = ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234}$
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

So the result would look like:
[image]

Comment: Welcome. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. See the following: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52943/background-color-of-breakable-box-removing-thin-blank-lines

Comment: @cacamailg I don't think the referenced question helps, as that is for a rectangular region (see my answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run this twice

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\def\savepos#1{\leavevmode\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\string\save@#1{{\the\pdflastxpos sp }{\the\pdflastypos sp }}}}

\def\xx#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo\csname save@#1\endcsname}
\def\yy#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo\csname save@#1\endcsname}

\def\hl#1#2{%
\ifx\save@a\@undefined
\else
\leavevmode\smash{\rlap{\vtop{%
\parindent\z@\parskip\z@
\leavevmode\color{yellow}\endgraf
\vskip-\baselineskip
\dimen@\xx{#1}%
\@tempdima\yy{#1}%
\@tempdimb\yy{#2}%
\loop
\ifdim\@tempdima>\@tempdimb
\leavevmode
      \kern\dimexpr\dimen@-\xx{#1}\relax
      \vrule width \dimexpr\xx{b}-\dimen@\relax height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox\endgraf
\dimen@\xx{a}%
\advance\@tempdima-\baselineskip
\repeat
\ifdim\@tempdima=\@tempdimb
\leavevmode
      \kern\dimexpr\dimen@-\xx{#1}\relax
      \vrule width \dimexpr\xx{#2}-\dimen@\relax height\ht\strutbox  depth\dp\strutbox\endgraf
\fi
}}}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\noindent\savepos{a}\hfill\savepos{b}

Completely unimportant text 
\hl{c}{d}\savepos{c}$ABC_{1234} = ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234} + ABC_{1234} - ABC_{1234}$\savepos{d}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain the code David?

Comment: @cacamailg not at this time of night:-)

Comment: @cacamailg basically, the positions at the beginning and at the end are saved, if they differ, a loop is used to produce the highlighting for the first line and all (possible) intermediate lines; when they differ, the highlighting for the only line is produced.

Comment: I understand that positions are saved (and it seems to use a `pdf`primitive for that. But what I want to understand is how is it saved, in which file, and how LaTeX in the second run gets the first and latest positions to highlight.

Comment: @cacamailg That's the `\savepos` macro which writes teh x,y coordinates (in sp) to the aux file. Look in the aux file and you will see the coordinates of a b c and d saved. (It would perhaps be better not to do a and b this way, they are the page margins so could be calculated in advance but allowing for then to be saved this way means it can work in minipage or tabular columns.