# Inline colorbox & linebreaks

Tags: typewriter, colorbox

First and foremost, I have found some solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113795/background-color-for-inline-math-with-linebreaks), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94965/wrapping-inline-long-lines-and-adding-background-color), and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113795/background-color-for-inline-math-with-linebreaks) but they *seem* overly complicated for what I am trying to accomplish.

### Problem

I am trying to somewhat reproduce the code environment "markdown-style" in LaTeX. I used a `colorbox` in conjunction with `texttt` to get a pretty satisfying look but it does not allow line breaks and thus breaks everything when used with paths or long lines.

### Question

It is my understanding that `colorbox` cannot be used to output multiple lines. What could help me achieve this while keeping the code *fairly* clean?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{black!30}{\textcolor{black!90}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\codeA}[1]{\colorbox{black!30}{\textcolor{black!90}{\texttt{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
test \code{code} test \code{+}

\lipsum[1]

\codeA{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you looked at `listings` or `minted`? Those are both packages for code highlighting and as far as I know they support background color as well as line breaking. I'd start with `minted` if you have no problem compiling with `-shell-escape`. `:)`

Comment: @Guilherme Z. Santos I do use minted when I need to display code blocks indeed. What I am looking for here is a way to show inline code snippets.

Comment: Both `minted` and `listings` offer macros to display inline code. Minted macro is: `\mintinline{<language>}{code}`.

Comment: @Guilherme Z. Santos Thank you for the heads up. I think I will be working with this as for now. I will keep looking for a way to manage to do so without `minted` when I find some time.

Comment: why would you want to do it without `minted`? If there's a specific reason you're looking to use the package less perhaps you should see the `listings` package, I ***think*** they are compatible . Not using listing packages at all will surely lead to an overcomplicated solution which you seem to want to avoid...