# Highlight inline formulas

Tags: math-mode, backgrounds, inline, border

I need either to add a color background or border around each *inline* formula. How?

I want to ensure every formula is no more wide that about the 1/2 of the width of text, in order to [publish them in Kindle, as I describe here](https://blog.mathematics21.org/2019/11/05/how-to-publish-a-math-science-article-or-book-at-amazon-for-free-no-need-for-scientific-journals-anymore/).

Comment: Please tell us how you initiate and terminate inline math mode: with `$...$` or with `\(...\)`?

Comment: Please also tell us which engine you employ to compile your document: pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, or something else?

Comment: @Mico Currently I use pdfTeX but may switch to XeTeX

Comment: @Mico I use `$...$`, but switching to `\(...\)` is possible (howeever requires a big amount of work)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135053/18083 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113795/18083

Comment: I don't know how to come up with a solution based on the capabilities of pdfTeX or XeTeX. However, it's now that hard to do, really, when using LuaTeX, thanks to Lua's library of powerful string functions. The answer I posted below works with both `$...$`and `\(...\)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of two LaTeX macros called `\InlineMathColorOn` and `\InlineMathColorOff`, which act as switches to activate and deactivate the Lua function called `inlinemath_yellow`. The Lua function first sets aside cases of `\$` and `$$`, then encases all instances of `$...$` and `\(...\)` in yellow boxes, and finally restores the cases of `\$` and `$$`. The Lua function operates through the `process_input_buffer` callback, which does its job at a very early stage of processing, well before TeX gets to apply its eyes, mouth, etc.

What this code doesn't do is allow automatic line breaking inside inline-math formualas. But then, you're not going to allow many such constructs in your book, are you?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\colorbox' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment

\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function inlinemath_yellow ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "\\%$" , "@@@@@@@@@@@@" )  -- instances of "\$"
  s = s:gsub ( "%$%$" , '""""""""""""' )  -- instances of "$$"
  s = s:gsub ( "(%$..-%$)" , function ( u )
           return "\\colorbox{yellow}{$"..u:sub(2,-2).."\\strut$}" 
      end )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\%(..-\\%))" , function ( u )
         return "\\colorbox{yellow}{\\("..u:sub(3,-3).."\\strut\\)}" 
      end )  
  s = s:gsub ( "@@@@@@@@@@@@" , "\\$" ) -- revert instances of "\$"
  s = s:gsub ( '""""""""""""' , "$$" )  -- revert instances of "$$"
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\InlineMathColorOn{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
  inlinemath_yellow , "InlineMathYellow" )}}
\newcommand\InlineMathColorOff{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback ("process_input_buffer" , 
  "InlineMathYellow" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\InlineMathColorOn} % activate by default

\begin{document}
$1+1+1\ne2$, 
$1$, 
\(a^2+b^2=c^2\), 
\(\$12.34\), 
\$12.34
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ % not inline math
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...and now all inline math is unbreakable.

Comment: @HenriMenke - If I understood the OP's objective correctly, it's to have a quick & dirty method for searching the entire document for instances of inline math -- and to make sure that none of these instances are wider than ca `0.5\textwidth`. If my understanding is correct, it shouldn't matter much that all inline math constructs are made unbreakable. Once the OP has fixed (or re-written) the inline formulas that need fixing, all he/she has to do is delete or comment out the instruction `\AtBeginDocument{\InlineMathColorOn}` and compile the document one more time. :-)

Comment: @HenriMenke - If highlighting all instances of inline math has to be a permanent feature of the document (the mind shudders), I'd definitely replace `\colorbox` with some other macro or environment that allows line-breaking of long-ish inline math terms. :-)